# _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'H'

Tags: python-3.x, text, pickle

I am Having Problem in Pickling, Is any body Help me to out of this problem....

```
import json
import flask
import keras
import pickle

app_port = 6000
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

with open('model_training/model/keras_mnist.mod', 'rb') as infile:
    model = (pickle.load(infile))

def inference(img):
    pred = model.predict(img)


@app.route('/mnist', methods=['POST'])
def default():
    try:
        request = flask.request
        # request should just be string representing a 28x28 ndarray
        # like '[[255, 255], [255, 255]]'
    except Exception as exc:
        return json.dumps({'service': exc})


if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(port=app_port)
```

When I am Running This Code:
I am Getting This Error:-

```
File "run.py", line 9, in <module>

model = (pickle.load(infile))

_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'H'.
```

Comment: what is has to do with Artificital intelligence, and image?

Comment: Did you find the solution...